# Get time passed always 0

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, datediff

This is what i am getting when i load the page

[image]

Code here:

```
echo "<b>Requested:</b><br>".round(abs(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") - date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['timestamp']))) / 60,2)." minute(s) ago<br>";
echo "<b>Current Time:</b><br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br>  ";
echo "<b>Requested Time:</b><br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['timestamp']))."<br>  ";
```

My problem is that it always says it was requested 0 minutes ago the image shows that it should be 7 minutes ago and counting . i have tried what the code in the link above shows ive tried messing with it with different formats and some give me huge numbers so i have come here for help

Comment: Is this being pulled from a MySQL database, and if so, what is the exact data type for the column `timestamp`? (assuming it is TIMESTAMP)

Comment: And if it is a MySql fetch and the datatype is date, make sure both PHP and MySQL are using the same date Format.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do math with a string, since the date function creates a string in the format you supplied.  Use datetime objects for this

```
$previousDate = $row['timestamp'];
$startdate = new DateTime($previousDate);
$endDate   = new DateTime();
$interval  = $endDate->diff($startdate);

$int = $interval->format('%i');
echo "<b>Requested:</b><br>" . $int ." minute(s) ago<br>";
```

This assumes that `$row['timestamp']` is in the format 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss' already.  For a unix style timestamp, you want to use an ampersand in your construct

```
$previousDate = new DateTime('@' . $row['timestamp']);
```

Comment: That works but only problem is it now counts the minutes but doesnt get the hours/days ect in there the same so instead of 1 hour 17 minutes it should just be 77 minutes ago you know what i mean?

Comment: Check out the documentation for [php's DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).  You can specify any string you want inside the format method.  I just chose %i for minutes because that's what your original code had.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    //$row['timestamp'] = 1419272871; As an example

    echo "<b>Requested:</b><br>".round(abs(strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row['timestamp'])))/60, 2)." minute(s) ago<br>";
    echo "<b>Current Time:</b><br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br>  ";
    echo "<b>Requested Time:</b><br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row['timestamp'])."<br>  ";

?>
```

Output:

```
Requested:
1686.53 minute(s) ago
Current Time:
2014-12-23 23:34:23
Requested Time:
2014-12-22 19:27:51
```